# graphical query language algorithms

Tags: sql

My intention is to write a graphical query language where users can drag and drop criteria into a GUI query designer, then the designer will generate appropriate SQL query code and return the appropriate result set. Do you know where I can learn more about SQL code generation or if similar tools like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at Microsoft Access's query designer to see how it works; it's relatively simple to use and you can compare how changes in the graphical representation affect the SQL statement and vice-versa.  It should give you a pretty good view of how joins are translated into SQL.

(I cringe to suggest Microsoft Access for *anything*, but in this case, it might be useful to you).